# Run animations only when in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a site stuffed with lots of ongoing (looped) javascript-animations, which I want to be running only when they show up in the viewport in order to save performance.

Is there any cheap trick for achieving this? ideas on how to save performance in this particular case are very welcome.

I tried it like this, but doesn't work. Probably because the function isn't being triggered when `triggerEffect` turns `true`:

```
var triggerEffect = false;

$(window).scroll(function(){

  var wScroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
      divTop = $('#effect-div').offset().top-$(window).height(),
      divBottom = $('#effect-div').offset().top+$('#effect-div').height();

  if (wScroll > divTop && wScroll < divBottom) {
    triggerEffect = true;
  } else {
    triggerEffect = false;
  }

});

$(document).ready(function loop() {
  setTimeout( function () {
    $("#effect-div").css("background-color", "blue")

    setTimeout(function () {
      $("#effect-div").css("background-color", "red")
    }, 200);
    if ( triggerEffect == true ) {
      loop();
    };

  }, 400);

});
```

for the full code (including html and css) check this out on [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/josialoos/pen/MGRzQX)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move the scroll function inside the document ready function, so in the end it should look like this:

```js
    var triggerEffect = false;

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery(window).scroll(function(){

      var wScroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
          divTop = $('#effect-div').offset().top-$(window).height() / 1.2,
          divBottom = $('#effect-div').offset().top+$('#effect-div').height() / 1.2;

          console.log("wScroll "+wScroll);
          console.log("divTop "+divTop);
          console.log("divBottom "+divBottom);

      if (wScroll > divTop && wScroll < divBottom) {
        triggerEffect = true;
        loop();
      } else {
        triggerEffect = false;
      }

      console.log("triggerEffectSCROLL "+triggerEffect);

    });
    });

function loop() {
      console.log("triggerEffectLOOP "+triggerEffect);
      setTimeout( function () {
        jQuery("#effect-div").css("background-color", "blue")

        setTimeout(function () {
          jQuery("#effect-div").css("background-color", "red")
        }, 200);
        if ( triggerEffect == true ) {
          loop();
        };

      }, 400);

    }
```

```css
    body {
      height: 3000px;
    }

    #effect-div {
      height: 300px;
      width: 500px;
      background-color: red;
      margin-top: 1000px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="effect-div">
</div>
```

Comment: this doesn't work. at least not in codepen. for some reason the loop-function isnt being executed ...